# How to set button image by variable?

Tags: ios, image, uibutton, set

i am trying to set the button image by variable like this:

```
[collideButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"key%@.png",[getKeyboarLabel]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

this is not working an error comes expected identifiers! i dont know where do i missed anything.

if i set image by this code:

```
[collideButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"keya.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

it works good..
now please tell me where is the problem in uper code?

Comment: did you mean `getKeyboardLabel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `[NSString stringWithFormat@"key%@.png", key]`;

```
NSString *imageFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%@.png", getKeyboarLabel];
[collideButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageFilename] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: mm.. just NSLog(@"Key is %@", yourLabelText); I wonder what is [getKeyboardLabel] ??? Who is receiver?

Comment: @Steve if added the correct implementation to the answer of Inject. It should work now.

Comment: i dont have repution to vote yer answer rckoenes! thank you it worked